# How can I connect to OpenVPN server using GitHub Actions workflow before connecting to an AWS remote server using SSH?

Tags: github-actions, workflow, openvpn-connect

I attempted to deploy using a GitHub Actions workflow, but failed due to OpenVPN setting. I want to connect to an AWS server using SSH, but in order to connect, I have to connect to OpenVPN first.

The information I know about OpenVPN is ca, cert, key, tls-crypt.
Can anyone please give me a clue about connecting to OpenVPN using GitHub Actions workflow?

the code provided below. I do not know if it works without openvpn username and password. I want to connect without username and password because I do not have them. I have only `.ovpn` file.

```
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

         - name: Install Open VPN
        run: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y openvpn

      - name: Connect VPN
        uses: golfzaptw/action-connect-ovpn@master
        id: connect_vpn
        with:
          PING_URL: ${{ secrets.REMOTE_HOST_URL }}
          FILE_OVPN: '.github/vpn/config.ovpn'
        env:
          CA_CRT: ${{ secrets.CA_CRT}}
          USER_CRT: ${{ secrets.USER_CRT }}
          USER_KEY: ${{ secrets.USER_KEY }}

      - name: Configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v4
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: ${{ env.AWS_REGION }}
```

Occurred below error

```
Run golfzaptw/action-connect-ovpn@master
/bin/sh: 2: ***: not found
/bin/sh: 3: ***: not found
/bin/sh: 4: ***: not found
/bin/sh: 5: ***: not found
/bin/sh: 6: ***: not found
/bin/sh: 7: ***: not found
/bin/sh: 8: ***: not found
/bin/sh: 9: ***: not found
/bin/sh: 10: ***: not found
/bin/sh: 11: ***: not found
/bin/sh: 12: -----END: not found
/bin/sh: 2: ***: not found
/bin/sh: 3: ***: not found
/bin/sh: 4: ***: not found
/bin/sh: 5: ***: not found
/bin/sh: 6: ***: not found
/bin/sh: 7: ***: not found
/bin/sh: 8: ***: not found
/bin/sh: 9: ***: not found
/bin/sh: 10: ***: not found
/bin/sh: 12: -----END: not found
/bin/sh: 2: ***: not found
/bin/sh: 3: ***: not found
/bin/sh: 4: ***: not found
/bin/sh: 5: -----END: not found
Error: Can't setup config /home/runner/work/apiserver/apiserver/.github/vpn/config.ovpn
```

Comment: Please edit your question title so you are not SHOUTING at us. You surely saw how the other questions look.

Comment: You need to have the OpenVPN client installed on your GHA runner. You can use its CLI to connect to your OpenVPN server (most probably, in the background mode) before SSHing to your AWS server. For Linux, see [Connecting to Access Server with Linux](https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/connecting-to-access-server-with-linux/). You might have to backup `/etc/resolv.conf` and later restore it also once you're done with VPN and need normal connectivity (if required depending on your use case).

Comment: See [Using secrets in GitHub Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/using-secrets-in-github-actions) to store your `.ovpn` file's contents if needed.

Comment: @Azeem thank you for help! I partially understand what you said. I provided the github action workflow above, can you give me a sample code which works?
I attemted so many times, but failed to connect open vpn.

Comment: @John: Failed? What's the error?  Please include that in your question.

Comment: @Azeem  oops, I updated the error!

Comment: Do you have `.github/vpn/config.ovpn` in the repo?

Comment: @Azeem thank you, i am so dumb... I have to add it

Comment: You started to use https://github.com/golfzaptw/action-connect-ovpn (which is **deprecated**) instead of https://github.com/kota65535/github-openvpn-connect-action.

Comment: @Azeem thank you for your help! can i ask you one more question?

according to the example(https://github.com/golfzaptw/action-connect-ovpn) 

i found there is a step that kills vpn. this step should be the last  step after sshing to aws server right?

Comment: @John: You're welcome! Issue resolved? Yeah, sure if it's related. Otherwise, it's better to create a new one.

Comment: @Azeem , yes it works perfectly! thank you for your reference!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the OpenVPN client installed on your GHA runner. You can use its CLI to connect to your OpenVPN server (most probably, in the background mode) before SSHing to your AWS server.

For example, see [Connecting to Access Server with Linux](https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/connecting-to-access-server-with-linux/). You may have to backup `/etc/resolv.conf` and later restore it also once you're done with VPN and need normal connectivity (if required depending on your use case).

To automate these things, you can find already published actions on the GHA [marketplace](https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions).